# Use multiple channels with the same router

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have Spring Integration project with several channels. I wish that some of the channels output will go to the same router.

So for example, for channel-1 I have:

```
<int:chain input-channel="channel-1" output-channel="channel-1-out>
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceA" method="doService" />
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceB" method="doService" />
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceC" method="doService" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="channel-1-out">
   <int:router>
      <bean class="com.foo.MyClass" />
   </int:router>
 </int:chain>
```

and for channel-2 I have to duplicate the router class:

```
<int:chain input-channel="channel-2" output-channel="channel-2-out>
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceD" method="doService" />
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceE" method="doService" />
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceF" method="doService" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="channel-2-out">
    <int:router>
      <bean class="com.foo.MyClass" />
    </int:router>
</int:chain>
```

The problem with that is that for 10 different channels I have to write 10 different routers, all pointing to the same router class. For me, it seems a bit tiresome and redundant, and it makes the ApplicationContext way to messy.

Is there a way the simply just add the wanted outputs to same router? Something like

```
<int:chain input-channel=
                        "channel-1-out" +
                        "channel-2-out" + 
                        "channel-3-out"....>
    <int:router>
      <bean class="com.foo.MyClass" />
    </int:router>
</int:chain>
```

EDIT:

Simple solution, set the output-channel of each chain to the router input-channel.

```
<int:chain input-channel="channel-1" output-channel="router>
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceA" method="doService" />
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceB" method="doService" />
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceC" method="doService" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="channel-2" output-channel="router>
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceD" method="doService" />
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceE" method="doService" />
    <int:service-activator ref="serviceF" method="doService" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="router">
   <int:router>
      <bean class="com.foo.MyClass" />
   </int:router>
</int:chain>
```

No need to declare multiple routers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently; but we do have an open [enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2708).

That said, why do you need to declare multiple routers? Simply declare one and set the output-channel of each chain to its input-channel.